# How can I know if an object is date or datetime?

Tags: ruby, class

I need to validate an object and know if it contains `Date` or `DateTime`. How can I do this?

Comment: I'd recommend learning about duck-typing. Instead of caring whether an object is a Date or a DateTime, see whether it can do what you want. The reason is, an object might not be a Date or DateTime but could wrap one of those. Looking to see what the object type is would mislead you when you could actually use the object for what you want. See http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/duck_typing.html.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "contains". If you want to know if an object is an instance of one of those classes, that's what you should be asking. In that case, `object.class` will tell you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:
[instance_of](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_of%3F)

```
object.instance_of? Date
object.instance_of? DateTime
```

So, you can do this:

```
if object.instance_of? Date
  puts "Its a Date"
elsif object.instance_of? DateTime
  puts "Its a DateTime"
end
```

Comment: You are most welcome. Glad that it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
object.instance_of?
```

DateTime is a subclass of Date, so whatever you can do with Date can be done with DateTime:

```
 object.kind_of?
 object.is_a?
```

`kind_of?` and `is_a?` are synonymous. `instance_of?` is different from the other two in that it only returns true if the object is an instance of that exact class, not a subclass.

For example, `5.is_a? Integer` and `5.kind_of? Integer` return true because 5 is a Fixnum and Fixnum is a subclass of Integer. However `5.instance_of? Integer` returns false.

Comment: Please read through the documentation for formatting questions and answers, and mimic the common look and feel for Q/A on Stack Overflow. SO is akin to a reference book so wild use of bold and not formatting code sections is out of place. As is, your answer is difficult to read and determine what you're saying.